# Ideas for a 2D game for a neural network to play

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, 2d-games, neat

I am currently trying to implement my own neural-network library, and I would like to test it by letting it (and networks made with other librarys) play a 2D game. The problem is I can't really find a good game for a neural network to play.

Requirements for the game:

- It should **not** involve skills like reaction time, precision. It should instead require some tactical skills.
- It should be easily scorable, in order to create an efficient evolutional algorithm.
- It should be relatively simple.
- It does not have to be a game that already exists, you can come up with one if you have an idea.
- It may be a single-player game (like mario) or a 1v1 game (like pong).

  - It must not be any kind of MMO, RPG etc. I am looking for a small kind of mini-game.

The game should be well playable by a neural network. This means it should have a fixed amount of inputs somehow normalizable between 0 and 1. Inputs can be sensors, angles to closest objects etc. inputs should NOT be the pixels of the screen because 3*1920*1080 is just too much. Up to about 100 inputs are manageable (because I am a beginner and can't afford to let my computer calculate for hours just to get one generation evolved or so).
Also the game should definitely be a 2D game since i am going to use a AWT JPanel to draw on.

Comment: How about Minesweeper? Or 2048?

Comment: Minesweeper is probably better solved with a standard algorithm... and 2048 has the problem that i can't really come up with any meaningful inputs...

Answer (score 4):

I'm the main developer of [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic).js, basically a neural network library with neuro-evolution built in to it. Just to give you some ideas, you might want to look at my following articles:

- [Agar.io AI](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/agario/)
- [Target-seeking AI](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/targetseeking/)

Some other suggestions:

- Snake
- Flappy bird
- Bomberman

Neural networks have been tested on most simple 2D games, so if you're stuck you will always find code that might help you.